# symfony console make:entity : How to not have @ORM\GeneratedValue on Id?

Tags: symfony

I want to be able to deserialize a json request using:

```
$user = $serializer->deserialize($request->getContent(), Book::class, 'json');
```

But the id is not filled because there is no setter on Id in Book entity after using

```
symfony console make:entity
```

That create an auto generation id and so not setter for Id

```
class Book
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

...

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
```

I found that we can change after generation:

```
class Book
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="NONE")
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

...

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function setId(int $id): self
    {
         $this->id = $id;
         return $this;
    }
```

So can I call symfony console make:entity with a no autogeneration on Id (so that I don't have to modify each time the class) ?
Or
How to deserialize to get also the id?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

Step 1:

Add id in the Entity constructor:

```
public function __construct($id)
{
    $this->id = $id;
}
```

Step 2:

Add this in your controller:

```
    // Handle the fact that doctrine Entity has no Id setter. Think to add a constructor with id as parameter in Entity
    $data = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);
    $book = new Book($data['id']);
    $serializer->deserialize($request->getContent(), Book::class, 'json', ['object_to_populate' => $book]);
```

And that'it!
Hope it helps.